# Prevent Amazon S3 bucket forcing download

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using an Amazon S3 bucket to store user uploads for public access.

When you click a link to the resource it seems to force a download even when the files could be viewed in the browser (ie JPGs, etc).

Comment: does that happen also when you use that link within an image html tag?  i.e. <img src="..."/>

Comment: No, images show up no problem when hosted there and if I enter the URL directly into the browser it renders the content. However if I add the URL to a hyperlink (with or without target specified) it downloads!

Comment: checkout this post: http://www.mayerdan.com/ruby/2013/02/17/s3-files-mime-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by TheZuck the problem was the content type wasn't being set at the point the file was uploaded.

I'm using an Amazon S3 PHP class (http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) so simply had to add the content type (`mime_content_type($file)` in PHP) when using the putObjectFile method:

```
$s3class->putObjectFile($file, S3BUCKET, $target_location, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, NULL, mime_content_type($file));
```